# How to run a scenario in a loop with Fitnesse

Tags: fitnesse

I am using Fitnesse for testing our project's API, and I have created scenario tables for each interface, so we could send the request anywhere by calling the scenario. And now we need to execute the scenarios in a loop, based on a random looping count.  Are there any fixtures or tables in Fitnesse that could help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't loop in Slim. FitNesse wiki format is not a programming language. This has been an active decision from the implementation of the Slim format/protocol. I don't see that changing.

If you want to loop, you should to do that inside your fixture code.

Technically, if you are using Fit style fixtures, there was a thing called a Decorator that let you do things to a decision table to run it multiple times. The old Fit Decorators are not compatible with Slim, if you are using Slim. Also, no one is maintaining these, as far as I know. http://fitdecorator.sourceforge.net